# Unable to do PUT operation -DjangoRESTFramework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, put, postman

**I am unable to do *PUT* operation in Django rest framework**, I am able to GET, POST, DELETE operation.

This is the error [image]
I have tried using @api_view but there also its not,
I mostly refer the [djangorestframework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) website

Below is my code:

*serializers.py*

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from snippets.models import Snippet
#from django.contrib.auth.models import *

class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
            class Meta:
                model = Snippet
                fields = ('id','title','code')
```

*Models.py*

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class Snippet(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')


class Meta:
    ordering = ('created',)
```

*Views.py*

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from snippets.serializers import SnippetSerializer

    class SnippetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        """
        API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
        """
        queryset = Snippet.objects.all().order_by('id')
        serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
```

*urls.py*

```
rom django.conf.urls import url, include
from rest_framework import routers
from django.contrib import admin
from snippets import views




router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'snippet', views.SnippetViewSet)


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),

]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation of [`DefaultRouter`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#defaultrouter), it looks like that `PUT` method can only be used with `{basename}-detail` type of URLs.

While you are using it directly on `/snippet` url where it is not allowed.

Comment: what i have to enter in the place of {basename}-detail. I read that documentation but not getting it

Comment: It means that you can use `PUT` method on a particular snippet that you have already created. So let's say the id of that snippet is `123` then you can try accessing it using `/snippet/123` and then use PUT method on this url.